# Aurelia: data is undefined

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I need help to get data from one aurelia page to another.
I made log in page where i ask username and password. Then i check if this user is in database. Problem is, that i do not know how to remember the username in next pages. I need username from here:

```
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client'

export class User{

constructor(userData){
    this.username= userData.username;
}
userData = {}
userList= []

getUser(x, y){
    console.log(x)
    this.username = x;
    console.log(y)    

    let client = new HttpClient();

    client.fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/'+ x)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(JSON.stringify(data.password) === '"'+y+'"'){
                console.log("Okei")
                var landingUrl = "http://" + window.location.host + "#/main";
                window.location.href = landingUrl
            }else{
                console.log("Wrong password")
                alert("Wrong password! Try again")
            }
        })


} 
}
```

to that page:

```
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client'
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { User } from '../home/index';

@inject(User)
export class Diet{
constructor(userData) {
    this.username = userData.username;
}

somethingSpecial() {
    console.log(this.username);
}

dietData = {}
dietList=[]


addDiet(){

    let client = new HttpClient();

    client.fetch('http://localhost:8080/diet/add', {
        'method': "POST",
        'body': json(this.dietData)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log("Server sent " + data.foodName);
    });
    document.getElementById("form").reset();
    this.somethingSpecial();
}

}
```

I have tried using the constructor, but right now it says that userData is undefined, so it does not get information from the first page. What i am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Look at storing your user session data in local storage - that should solve your issues.

Comment: Or, look at this article on Shared State - https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/shared-state-in-aurelia/

Answer (score 0):

Use a singleton. In Aurelia this is as easy as simply making a class and injecting it.

Take the following cut-down example from one of my own applications.

Note: This was originally Typescript but I think I got it right.

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-http-client';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Auth {

    constructor(http) {

        this.http
            .get('/api/auth/userinfo')
            .then(response => {
                this.userInfo = response.content;
            });
    }
}
```

Once this is done you can call this class from anywhere and have the user information exposed without the need to call the server each time.

```
import { Auth } from '../auth';

@inject(Auth)
export class AddNote {
    constructor(auth) {
        console.log(auth.userInfo.username); // Should return username
    }
}
```

For more information on this, the article thebluefox shared in the comments of your question is a good read.